# leveneTest for several variables

Tags: r, loops, equality, lapply, variance

How can I apply leveneTest on each dependent variable seperately and after that how I can extract the P-value of each analysis and bring all the p-values in a matrix.

```
responses <- as.matrix(mtcars[,-c(4,8,9)])
leveneTest(responses~as.factor(am)*as.factor(vs),data=mtcars)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
responses <- as.matrix(mtcars[,-c(4,8,9)])
results <- data.frame(var = colnames(responses), p = rep(NA,dim(responses)[2]))
results$p <- apply(responses,2,function(x) {leveneTest(x ~ as.factor(mtcars$am)*as.factor(mtcars$vs))[1,3]})
```